# How to setup whatever.localhost.dev to resolve into 127.0.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, dnsmasq

I'm running Ubunut 12.04

I want *localhost.dev to point to 127.0.0.1.

Ubuntu 12.04 comes with dnsmasq-base installed with network-manager. But there is no /etc/dnsmasq.conf.

1. So I installed the dnsmasq package
2. The /etc/dnsmasq.conf file appeared
3. I added: address=/localhost.dev/127.0.0.1
4. sudo restart network-manager

Doesn't work. How do I solve this?

EDIT: Turns out it works after a restart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After configuring settings , we have to restart dnsmasq service :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

Update :

If you want to use wild card (*) then you can use dot (.) then dnsmasq to resolve `WHATEWER_YOU_PUT_HERE.yourmachine.yourdomain` to the same ip.

Example :

```
 address=/.localhost.dev/127.0.0.1
```

Comment: No. The dot wasn't necessary. It works without it. A full restart made it work.

Comment: @Andreyy Rahul's answer still correct, you need to restart dnsmasq instead of network-manager. Full restart/reboot is not necessary

Comment: The answer about the restart might be correct while the "dot" change is not necessary. @Rahul change the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Andreyy as you mentioned `*localhost.dev` in your question, to apply on all subdomain we should use dot like `.localhost.dev`

Comment: The OP didn't ask for subdomains. Or, it wasn't clear. He specified `*localhost.dev`, not `*.localhost.dev`.